# What's the max file mapping size in 64bits machine

Tags: linux, 64-bit, filemap

I'm new to 64-bits architecture. Could you tell me what's MAX file size supported by file mapping in 64 bits linux machine. I want to open more than 20GB files by file mapping, is it available?

I write a sample code. But it causes **Bus Error** when I get the value of the pointer in GBSIZE offset:

```
unsigned char* pCur = pBegin + GBSIZE;
//pBegin is the pointer returned by mmap
printf("%c",*pCur);
```

BTW, `printf("%c",*pBegin );` works fine. and my address sizes : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

//#define FILEPATH "smallfile"
#define FILEPATH "bigfile"
#define GBSIZE (1024L*1024L*1024L)
#define TBSIZE (1024L*GBSIZE)
#define NUMSIZE  (20L * GBSIZE)
//#define NUMSIZE  (10)
#define FILESIZE (NUMINTS * sizeof(int))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    unsigned char *pBegin;

    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file for reading");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pBegin = mmap(0, NUMSIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (pBegin == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /** ERROR happens here!!! **/
    unsigned char* pCur = pBegin + GBSIZE;
    printf("%c",*pCur);

    if (munmap(pBegin, NUMSIZE) == -1) {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pszPointer` appears to be uninitialised.  You'll get better answers if you post a complete program that demonstrates the problem - preferably as a new question.

Comment: thanks, i made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Regarding the bus error, POSIX states: "References within the address range starting at pa and continuing for len bytes to whole pages following the end of an object shall result in delivery of a SIGBUS signal."  http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html
If you have further questions then post a new question.

Answer (score 14):

Although pointers are 64-bit wide, most processors do not actually support virtual addresses using the full 64 bits.  To see what size virtual addresses your processor supports, look in `/proc/cpuinfo` (48 bits is typical).

```
grep "address sizes" /proc/cpuinfo
```

Additionally, half of the virtual address space is used by the kernel and not available to userspace - leaving 47 bits in the current Linux implementation.

However, even taking this into account, you will still have *plenty* of room for a 20GB file.  47 bits in theory means a virtual address space of 128TB.

Comment: I've tried to mmap a 20GB file by file mapping. but it causes Bus Error when I get the value of the pointer in GBSIZE offset:
unsigned char* pCur = pBegin + GBSIZE; //pBegin is the pointer returned by mmap
printf("%c",*pszPointer);

BTW, "printf("%c",*pBegin );" works fine.

Comment: If you add the offset to the beginning of the mapping, you get a pointer to the byte BEYOND the end of the mapping, therefore a bus error would be exactly what I'd expect.

Answer (score 6):

From the `mmap(2)` man page:

```
   void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
              int fd, off_t offset);
```

`length` is a `size_t`, which on 64-bit machines is 64 bits in length. Therefore yes, you can theoretically map a 20GB file.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit addresses allow for many orders of magnitude more than 20 GB.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer was originally edited into the question by OP)

You have requested a 20GB map onto a file which was only 50MB in size.

As described by [the mmap man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap), `mmap` succeeds when you request the length too big, however it will give `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` when you actually try to read beyond the end of the underlying file.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with MarkR, you are dereference an invalid address.

```
// A bug in these lines.
unsigned char* pCur = pBegin + GBSIZE;      
printf("%c",*pCur);  

unsigned char* pEnd = pBegin + NUMSIZE;  
unsigned char* pLast = pEnd - 1;
unsigned char* pCur = pLast;
```

I modified your code to use HUGE TLB flags as the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define MAP_HUGETLB     0x40000         /*  create a huge page mapping */
#define MAP_HUGE_SHIFT  26
#define MAP_HUGE_1GB    (30 << MAP_HUGE_SHIFT)

#define KSIZE 1024L
#define MSIZE (1024L*1024L)
#define GSIZE (1024L*1024L*1024L)
#define TSIZE (1024L*GSIZE)

#define INIT_MEM 0
// Fail on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
// Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0:x86_64
// #define NUMSIZE  (16L * TSIZE)

// mmap ok; init: got killed; signal 9
// #define NUMSIZE  (8L * TSIZE)

// Got killed signal 9
// #define NUMSIZE  (1L * TSIZE)

// OK
// #define NUMSIZE  (200L * GSIZE)

// OK
#define NUMSIZE  (20L * GSIZE)
typedef unsigned long long ETYPE;

#define MEMSIZE (NUMSIZE*sizeof(ETYPE))
#define PGSIZE (16*KSIZE)

void init(ETYPE* ptr) {
        *ptr = (ETYPE)ptr;
}

int verify(ETYPE* ptr) {
        if (*ptr != (ETYPE)ptr) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: 0x%016llx != %p.\n", *ptr, ptr);
                return -1;
        }
        else {
                fprintf(stdout, "OK: 0x%016llx = %p.\n", *ptr, ptr);
        }
        return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    ETYPE *pBegin;

    int flags = MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB | MAP_HUGE_1GB;
    printf("mmap memory size:%lu GB\n", MEMSIZE/GSIZE);
    pBegin = (ETYPE*) mmap(0, MEMSIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, flags, -1, 0);
    if (pBegin == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ETYPE* pEnd = pBegin + NUMSIZE;
    ETYPE* pCur = pBegin;

#if INIT_MEM
    while (pCur < pEnd) {
            init(pCur);
            // ++pCur;  //slow if init all addresses.
            pCur += (PGSIZE/sizeof(ETYPE)); 
    }
#endif

    init(&pBegin[0]);
    init(&pBegin[NUMSIZE-1]);

    verify(&pBegin[0]);
    verify(&pBegin[NUMSIZE-1]);

    if (munmap(pBegin, MEMSIZE) == -1) {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    }
    return 0;
}
```