# How to increase memory mapped file space in linux

Tags: linux

I am using linux. Does the Operating System setup restrict the amount of space for mmap files? If yes, how can I increase the same or how can I set it as unlimited?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127855/what-is-the-size-limit-for-mmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159456/whats-the-max-file-mapping-size-in-64bits-machine